# Export JSON Data to Excel in '.xlsx' format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel

I have used this function to convert my JSON data to Excel with styling. Excel file is getting saved with '.xls' format. But I need to save it it in '.xlsx' format.

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
   
   var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
          for (var key in table[i]) {
              if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                  col.push(key);
              }
          }
      }

      // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
      var tempTable = document.createElement("table");
      tempTable.setAttribute("id", "testtable");

      // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

      var tr = tempTable.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
          th.innerHTML = col[i];
          tr.appendChild(th);
      }

      // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
      for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

          tr = tempTable.insertRow(-1);

          for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
              var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              tabCell.innerHTML = table[i][col[j]];
          }
      }
   
   
   
   
   
   
    if (!table.nodeType) table = tempTable;
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: tempTable.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Can any body help me to save this data in '.xlsx' format ?? Any change require in this function ???

Comment: @aspire Can u tell how to do ?? or any other approach  u can suggest

Comment: @apire It wont preserve styling. Inside JSON, I have one field which contains data in HTML format e.g str1: "<p><strong>test</strong></p>"

Comment: @aspire Can u check this error when trying to use XLSX ?

data - JSON object

XLSX.writeFile(data, 'out.xlsb');

Getting this error in console

xlsx.full.min.js:18 Uncaught Error: Invalid Workbook(…)

Comment: @aspire Getting data in excel with html tags